# In PostgreSQL (and maybe other engines), why does the UNION statement consider NULL values the same, while the UNIQUE constraint does not?

Tags: sql, null, duplicates, union, dbnull

I understand that the SQL standard allows multiple NULL values in a column that is part of the UNIQUE constraint.

What I don't understand is why the UNION construct (at least in PostgreSQL,) treats NULL values as the same. For example:

```
$ select * from tmp_a;
 a | b
---+---
 a | b
 a |
   |
(3 rows)

$ select * from tmp_b;
 a | b
---+---
 a | c
 a |
   |
(3 rows)

$ select a, b from tmp_a union select a, b from tmp_b order by 1, 2;
 a | b
---+---
 a | b
 a | c
 a |
   |
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The General Rule in the SQL-92 Standard is as follows:

13.1 'declare cursor' (remember `ORDER BY` is part of a cursor) 
General Rule 3b:

> the following special treatment of
>   null values. Whether a sort key value
>   that is null is considered greater or
>   less than a non-null value is
>   implementation-defined, but all sort
>   key values that are null shall either
>   be considered greater than all
>   non-null values or be considered less
>   than all non-null values.

The SQL-89 stated the same a little more clearly IMO:

> Although `x = y` is unknown if both
>   `x` and `y` are `NULL` values, in the
>   context of `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and
>   `DISTINCT`, a `NULL` value is
>   identical to or is a duplicate of
>   another `NULL` value.

I would guess that PostgreSQL is performing a sort to remove duplicates as required by `UNION` and is grouping `NULL` values together in line with Standards.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a more primary source, but according to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Grouping_and_sorting), there is a special case for NULLs when it comes to grouping operations. For those operations, like DISTINCT and UNION, NULL is "not distinct" from NULL, even though the two NULLs are also "not equal".

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting [web page](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) about this on the SQLite site with a survey of differences among SQL implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The treatment of nulls in SQL is fundamentally inconsistent and sometimes contradictory. There is no logically sound basis behind the behaviour of nulls in SQL. You just have to learn the different rules that apply in different places and either apply them or work around them.